# Entity Framework Model First and Code First TPH issue

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-model-first

I'm facing two problems by trying to make a model first or code first using TPH concept.

The problem is that I need to use table per hierarchy at three levels, so that:

When I use Model First, the last hierarchy entity (third level) does not saves in database. I create an instance from this entity which inherits an abstract entity, which inherits another abstract entity. The data of two abstract entities are saved, but the last entity not saves. If the inheritance goes at maximum two levels works fine.

If I try to use Code First the problem is that I cannot share attributes with same name, for example: ClassB and ClassC has a property named "Name", and both inherits ClassA. When I map to generate database, I want to create only a sql table called ClassA, but it does not share the column "Name", it creates Name and Name1 columns.

I need to do one of this models works, otherwise I can't use inheritances in my model.

Hope some help!

Thanks

Comment: If ClassC and ClassB share the Name property, why not to put it in ClassA ?

Comment: It was only a sample, the model is so much complex, so that I cannot put the "Name" property in ClassA, because there are other classes which cannot inherit this property.